# How to speed up RDP on Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows, networking, remote-desktop, compression

My connection speed for upload is 100 KB/s

But now I'm looking at resource monitor and it only consumes 6-15 KB/s (send/receive) for mstsc.exe service.

I'm starting to think that I've enabled some huge compression settings and it gets compressed that much that it lags because of the connection speed limit. I configured RDP 1 year ago and now I don't remember which settings did I tune.

Can anyone suggest which settings should I adjust (in gpedit) to use all my upload speed bandwidth for remote desktop usage ?

I don't care about image quality, speed is the most important thing.

Comment: I remember there was a post somewhere saying that having the Desktop Experience enabled would speed RDP sessions as opposed to turning off all the graphical enhancements.

Comment: Have you tried changing the settings in the RDP *client* to use a smaller desktop and turn off effects?

Comment: I have all effects turned off, 15 bit colors. I noticed some minor improvement in speed when I changed 
"Optimize visual experience when using RemoteFX" - Screen capture rate- highest; screen image quality: lowest. 
Also "Configure compression for RemoteFX data" - Enabled (Balances memory and network bandwidth)

Comment: Lag is mostly unrelated to bandwidth. What type of Internet uplink are we talking about? What time does `ping superuser.com` display?

Comment: Also, 128 kilobit/s is coincidentally exactly 16 kilobyte/s. Are you sure about the units?

Comment: My home PC's upload speed is 100 KB/s, DL 10 Mbps. 
Server's (where RDP is hosted) 100/100 Mbps

Comment: ping superuser.com

Ping statistics for 151.101.1.69:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 28ms, Maximum = 29ms, Average = 28ms

Comment: I forgot to mention that RDP connection shows 3 bars (out of 4) and I have enabled all possible settings for UDP but it's still not showing that UDP is enabled in connection info window...

Comment: bump.. I haven't been able to enable UDP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated to Windows Server 2016 and UDP is working now. Video streaming has improved a lot.